# Is there a way in which I can grant only read access of a procedure in snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created a Procedure in snowflake

I want to give read-privileges of that stored procedure in snowflake to some other user/role.

```
GRANT USAGE ON PROCEDURE
    get_column_scale(float) 
    TO ROLE other_role_name_here;
```

I believe the above command would also give the write access, which I don't want. Is there a way in which only read access can be granted

Comment: Usage will grant execute privilege. [Refer](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#stored-procedure-privileges) for allowed privs on stored procedures.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only privilege to assign to a procedure is `usage`, so if you want a role to be able to read the definition for the procedure but not run it, then you can use a stored procedure defined to execute with owner's rights:

```
create or replace procedure read_procedure(PROCEDURE_PATH string)
returns string
language javascript
execute as owner
as
$$
    let rs = snowflake.execute({sqlText: `select get_ddl('procedure', ?) as DDL`, binds:[PROCEDURE_PATH]});
    rs.next();
    return rs.getColumnValue('DDL');
$$;
    
create or replace procedure FOO(S string)
returns string
language javascript
as
$$
    return S;
$$;

grant usage on procedure READ_PROCEDURE(string) to role MY_ROLE;

call read_procedure('FOO(string)');
```

In this setup, make sure that `MY_ROLE` has usage on procedure `read_procedure(string)` but does not have usage on procedure `foo(string)`. That way the role will be able to see the definition of `foo(string)` without the privilege required to execute it (usage).

Note that since the `read_procedure(string)` procedure runs with owner's rights, anyone calling it will be able to read any procedure that the owner's role can read.

Edit: You can also read the SP in parts in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PROCEDURES view. You can grant select on that view without granting USAGE on the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

For clarification, attempting to grant select on a view in INFORMATION_SCHEMA will error, even with ACCOUNTADMIN role.   To get around this, create a view on top of any of the IS views desired, then grant select on the created view, as mentioned here:  https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/Insufficient-privileges-to-operate-on-schema-INFORMATION-SCHEMA-when-trying-to-share-the-INFORMATION-SCHEMA-of-a-manually-created-database