# Viewing Procedures in Schema without Ability to Run

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am really struggling to find how to grant a role the ability to view stored procedures in a schema in which the users will not have the ability to call said procedures.

The closest I could find was the MONITOR permissions, but the DESCRIBE action appears to only return views and tables at the schema level.

[General DESCRIBE Command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc.html)

[DESCRIBE Schema Command](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc-schema.html)

Comment: Recently asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72885037/is-there-a-way-in-which-i-can-grant-only-read-access-of-a-procedure-in-snowflake/72886366#72886366

Comment: Solution in the above question solves this, tested and it works.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely an option, but it's kind of insane there is nothing built in for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way in which I can grant only read access of a procedure in snowflake?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72885037/is-there-a-way-in-which-i-can-grant-only-read-access-of-a-procedure-in-snowflake)